# How to know which interface is connected to particular machine?

Tags: server, interface, ping

I have a server with a lot of interfaces, and only one interface is assigned IP address, this interface is kept for management.

but other interfaces are connected to the other server.

I want to know which interface is actually connected to the outside server.

Here, I tried to ping to the machine IP with particular interface `ping -I eth1 x.x.x.x`.
But not able to ping with the interface even though I know this is connected to the server.
All the packet is only going via the management `eth0`.

Is there a better way to find out which interface is connected to a particular machine?
I know the machine IP address

I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please include which operating system you are using.

Comment: If you're using Linux, does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/399710/871246) work for you?